# Read Tag Name (Node NAme) XMl VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file content:

```
<HldgVal>
<Amt Ccy="BRL">25641.94</Amt>
<Sgn>true</Sgn>
```

The "BRL" indicated is the Currency for the amount 25641.94, however, when I try to read the tag  Amt Ccy="BRL"  in order to get the currency symbol, I just get the  node name "AMT" instead of  Amt Ccy="BRL".

I am using  the following code :

```
MoedaCaixa = fundoElement2.ChildNodes.Item(1).FirstChild.nodeName
```

Does anyone knows how to get the full name "Amt Ccy="BRL"" so that I can read the currency?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

AMT is node name Ccy is node attribute

Comment: I got it, the syntax would be :

 fundoElement2.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("Ccy").Text

Tks a lot

Answer (score 1):

AMT is the node name and Ccy is the node attribute. What you want is the node attribute value. Try this:

```
MoedaCaixa = fundoElement2.Attributes.getNamedItem("BRL").Text
```